# Stripe iOS SDK - Incompatible block pointer types sending

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

The Stripe SDK is causing a build a failure.  The specific error is:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending '__strong STPAPIResponseBlock _Nonnull' (aka 'void (^__strong)(ResponseType  _Nullable __strong, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
>
> to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(STPSource * _Nullable __strong, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)'

The code it is failing on is the following within STPAPIClient.m...

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)retrieveSourceWithId:(NSString *)identifier clientSecret:(NSString *)secret responseCompletion:(STPAPIResponseBlock)completion {
    NSString *endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", APIEndpointSources, identifier];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"client_secret": secret};
    return [STPAPIRequest<STPSource *> getWithAPIClient:self
                                               endpoint:endpoint
                                             parameters:parameters
                                           deserializer:[STPSource new]
                                             completion:completion];
}
```

Everything was working fine - and then I believe Xcode updated.  Now I get this problem.  I tried building a new app from scratch with nothing in it other then the Stripe SDK (installed via CocoaPods) and that failed to.

Before I rollback to an earlier version of Xcode - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I should have mentioned - I'm running XCode 11.4 and targeting iOS 13.4

Comment: FYI you can edit a question to include more information instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

XCode 11.4 broke the stripe pod v19.0 and it got fixed in v19.0.1 
to upgrade the stripe pod, run `pod update Stripe`

Comment: I try your steps but I do not install v19.0.1.

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci new pod version is 19.0.1 and the latest Stripe version is 14.0.1 atm

Answer (score 16):

**Update with fixes**: "We've released v14.0.1, v15.0.2, v17.0.3, and v19.0.1 to Cocoapods with fixes for this issue.": 
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/1525#issuecomment-604037716

**Older post info**:

This is fixed by Stripe in this change: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/pull/1526

If you're stuck on an older version of Stripe, you can try applying the two changes to your local version. (Changes at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/pull/1526/files).

Comment: Whats different in v14.0.1, v15.0.2, v17.0.3, and v19.0.1 ? Couldn't find suitable one.

Comment: client had fixed v11.3.0 ... decided easier to patch than question why

Answer (score 9):

I did this:

in **Podfile.lock** i have changed   **- Stripe (19.0.0)** to   **- Stripe (19.0.1)** and then in terminal in the directory of ios ran **"pod update Stripe"**.  I'm using flutter and for me it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Also ran into this, but am on the v14 version of the stripe pod.  The only option I can find for people in my position is to revert back to xcode 11.3.1.

Comment: You can bump your Stripe pod version to 14.0.1. They released fix in that version

Comment: Just running into this issue now and when I update, I then start getting an error for 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found on the import in TPSCardFieldManager.h and nothing I try seems to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your stripe SDK to Version 19.0.1 to fix this issue.

pod 'Stripe', '~> 19.0.1'

OR else update your stripe pod to latest version by pod update command.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, it was xcode 11.4 update and i was running stripe v15.0.1.

I´ve just updated my stripe version to v15.0.2. Depending your version you can check this:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/1525#issuecomment-604037716

Answer (score 0):

I set my Stripe SDK to version 19.0.1 in my Pod file and ran the pod update command